# is there a way to get the output from javac when running maven

Tags: maven, stdout, javac, stderr

Sometimes I run maven and get a compilation error, but there's no way to know what's wrong because maven swallows the output from javac.  Is there a way to get it show this output?

Comment: have you tried running it with the -X flag?

Comment: Indeed I have.  It tells me how maven invoked javac, but unless I'm missing something, it does NOT tell me the output FROM javac.

Comment: Can you show an example output... also how you called Maven and which versions of JDK, Maven, Plugins etc you are using?

Comment: calling maven via IntelliJ, but I don't think it matters; if there's any way to do this at all, I will be happy.  If I have to switch to a different IDE or a different JDK or disable/enable some plugins, that is fine with me.  As far as I know, maven simply doesn't provide this feature.  If I'm wrong, I'm willing to jump through hoops to get the output.

Comment: You are doing this from the command line?

Comment: No, from IDE, but I'm willing to do this via command line instead if it has any chance of helping.

Comment: Okay, I am a moron.  The reason I could not get output is because it could not launch the compiler.  Sigh.  Maven really could have given a clearer error message here.